# If we make a Mars or moon station, how would the carbon and water cycle work if the Earth was destroyed?

Tags: mars, the-moon, water, carbon

If it costs 50k to fly 1 pound to space, how much would the machine cost?  I'm a 7th grader and I need help on my project.  How would the carbon and water cycle machines work?  This is hypothetical.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of  [If we create a functioning space station or mars colony. Then what about the carbon and water cycle and how would that work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63312/if-we-create-a-functioning-space-station-or-mars-colony-then-what-about-the-car)

Comment: Please stop asking the same bad question over and over. Edit your original question to fix the problems with it  instead. Bottom line, the questions you are posting cannot be answered, because they cover too much ground, and you do not explain your assumptions. If the Earth is destroyed, the cost of payload to orbit is irrelevant.

Comment: @kylerDucey - I have edited your other question to focus on the water and carbon bit, I recommend editing this one to be about weight - how much such a system might weigh scaled up to say 100 people, ideally linking to an example system you are interested in. Once you have the weight you can do your own math to work out costs to either orbit or Mars. Suggest removing the 'if earth destroyed' part since for all feasible life support systems everybody still dies.

Comment: Agreed, the Earth destruction part puts it in worldbuilding territory, not for here.

Comment: It doesn't cost anywhere near 50k to fly a pound into space.   Current rates for Falcon 9 are roughly $2500/kg.  But you aren't going to be bringing water up from Earth in quantity anyway.  Both the Moon and Mars have extensive water deposits, and we are finding more every day.